# EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'OrtGetApiBase' in DLL 'onnxruntime'

Tags: c#, onnx, onnxruntime

I am trying to run an sklearn onnx model in C# 4.8 framework on Windows 10 Pro with VS 2019, I have used the following code using examples in:

https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-sci-kit-learn-models-in-net-core-applications-90e24e572f64

https://vkontech.com/making-predictions-in-c-with-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-via-onnx/

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automl-onnx-model-dotnet

I have imported using nuget

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime -Version 1.9.0
Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu -Version 1.9.0
Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxTransformer -Version 1.6.0
Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.MKLML -Version 1.6.0
Install-Package Microsoft.ML -Version 1.5.5
```

when i run this line of code:

```
InferenceSession session = new InferenceSession(modelPath);
```

I receive this error:

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.NativeMethods' threw an exception.'

EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'OrtGetApiBase' in DLL 'onnxruntime'.

in:

```
public SessionOptions()
    : base(IntPtr.Zero, true)
{
    NativeApiStatus.VerifySuccess(NativeMethods.OrtCreateSessionOptions(out handle));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue should already be resolved here: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/9260

In short, you need to load the package (onnxruntime.dll) into the startup project to use OrtGetApiBase.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me for an ASP.NET 5 project, where I use onnxruntime in the startup project. Tried everything I could find on the net.

Comment: Partially fixed by finding the native runtime DLLs and copying manually to the application's directory.